# Grab host app active record objects when engine and host app have same model names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a host app `unicorn` with the model `Article`.

I also have a mountable engine hooked into the host app called `blorgh`. It also has a model: `Article`. It is namespaced, so the table name for the engine's Article is actually `blorgh_articles`.

While inside the engine I want to grab the host app's `article`, ***not*** the engine's `article`. Is this possible?

```
#blorgh/app/controllers/blorgh/articles_controller.rb
require_dependency "blorgh_application_controller"
module Blorgh
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @articles = Article.all #properly grabs all the engine's articles
      @host_app_articles = main_app.Article.all # this doesn't work. It should grab the host app's articles.
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `::Article` to refer to the top-level namespace class, and `MyEngine::Article` to refer to the engine's class.

While using `Article` alone within the `MyEngine` namespace will resolve correctly, doing this introduces a couple of pitfalls:

- It makes it confusing to understand your code as there are multiple references to an ambiguous `Article`.
- If you ever rename your `MyEngine::Article` class to something else, but miss a reference to `Article` during this change, the same code will now change in meaning to refer to the global `::Article`.  This may or may not break your specs, and it may introduce unintended behavior.

Comment: thank you.  That looks like it works!  `Article.all` properly grabs the engines articles even though I didn't put `Blorgh::Article.all`.  Would you say it is ok to do this?

Comment: It will work for the moment, but I wouldn't recommend it - see updated.